# TypeError: unhashable type: 'dict' Python/Flask

Tags: python

So, I'm working on a little program that is supposed to send values to a `firestore database`, almost everything is working fine, but I get an error from this part of the code. I'm trying to save the `string` that is inside `temp`

```
 if block == "ITEMS":
        champs = form.areaItems.data #Get the user input text field from the WTForm (it's a dict for whatever reason)
        itemsChamps = ItemsChamps(champs.values()) #Stock the dict value inside itemsChamps 
        temp = next(iter(itemsChamps.name)) #Get the 1st value from itemsChamps (I only want the 1st value)
        data = {
            "items": {
                champs: {
                    "string": temp
                }
            }
        }
```

Here is the error :

```
File "C:\[..]\flaskblog\routes.py", line 63, in ajouter

"string": temp

TypeError: unhashable type: 'dict'
```

My code may look a bit """confusing""", I'm a newbie, sorry for that !

Edit 1 : It work now !

I feel so dumb right now, I was confused a bit by all the code I wrote, there was a few mistake :

```
        if block == "ITEMS":
        champs = form.itemsFields.data #I was using the wrong form field...
        itemsChamps = ItemsChamps(form.areaItems.data.values()) #I'm now getting all the value from the right field
        temp = next(iter(itemsChamps.name)) #Didn't touch this, it work
        data = {
            "items": {
                champs: {
                    "string": temp
                }
            }
        }
```

Thanks you for giving me a little of your time !

Comment: Shouldn't `champs` in the dict (as key) be literal string `"champs"`? The value is already stored in `temp`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is with this piece of code. `champs` is a dictionary, and you are using it as a key, dict key has to be a str, int, float (in general something that can be hashed and not a dictionary)

```
data = {
            "items": {
                champs: {
                    "string": temp
                }
            }
        }
```

If `champs["user_input"]` is the data you are interested in you can change `champs` to `champs["user_input"]` to solve this.

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to use a dict as a dict-key, to cite your comment: "is a dict for some reason". Dicts are not hashable and therefore cannot be used as keys. Maybe extract the data from the dict and use this as key?